# Asp.net core MVC Dependency injection - required properties in constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In an asp.net core mvc project, i have an abstract `ViewModel` class, for a layout, which *requires* some properties to function properly, and each concrete page's `ViewModel` derives from it:

```
public abstract class Layout
{
    // required to function properly
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    // required to function properly
    public IEnumerable<Foo> FooList { get; set; }

    protected Layout()
    {
        // Populate FooList from an util caching class?
    }
}

public class ViewModelHome : Layout {}
public class ViewModelProducts : Layout {}
```

The layout requires a `FooList`, which is populated from a database or a cache, since it is data not often changed.

I would like to avoid to putting each required field in the constructor in order to make it not too verbose, and I would like to avoid the following for each derived class:

```
var model = new ViewModelHome();
model.FooList = .....
```

In asp.net core caching is available through DI of `IMemoryCache`, so I cannot write something like this:

```
    public abstract class Layout
    {           
       protected Layout()
       {
           var cacheClass = new MyCacheClass(...IMemoryCache??...);
           this.FooList = cacheClass.GetFooList();        
       }        
    }
```

This is because I'm creating `Layout` on my own in a service, in turn called from controllers.

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMainService _service;

    public MainController(IMainService service)
    {
       _service = service;
    }


    public IActionResult Home()
    {              
       return View(_service.GetHomeViewModel());
    }
    public IActionResult Products()
    {
        return View(_service.GetProductsViewModel());
    }
 }
```

My question is: should i put in the abstract class constructor the logic for getting data from database or cache?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't make sense try enhancing the constructor in the derived class?

Comment: If you want to have access to the DI-Container (eg RequestServiceCollection), you have to get access to them, where you initialize your class and set it as Property in the public constructor. If you want I can show you an example.

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do? Sounds like your trying to implement a caching service of some sort to pre-populate some properties on a base class.

Comment: Passing dependencies via constructor is pretty clean approach, because it makes **IMMEDIATELY** visible which services are **REQUIRED**. But if you need to inject caching in an abstract class, its basically a sign of bad software design. Did you consider using **decorator pattern** to wrap the actually logic around a cache wrapper?

Comment: Additional note, if you have more than a couple of dependencies (4, 5 or more), then its also a very good hint that your class does too much and that the functionality needs to be split across multiple classes/services

Comment: Well since you mentioned `ViewModel` in the update: ViewModels shouldn't have any dependencies (in ASP.NET Core - different story for WPF/Desktop applications, since there's no bindings, notifications and stuff in ASP.NET (Core)'s ViewModels)

Comment: Agree with @Tseng here. This is bad design to have dependencies in view models. My understanding is that you want to setup some common properties for all your view models. In order to resolve this I would recommend you to implement some kind of initializer (e.g. `IViewModelInitializer`) which would be injected in controller and then called for all view models in order to initialize them. You can then inject all the dependencies (caching, repositories etc) in this initializer.

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich i agree, can you please write some pseudo code? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad design to have dependencies in view models. My understanding is that you want to setup some common properties for all your view models. In order to resolve this I would recommend you to implement some kind of initializer (e.g. `IViewModelInitializer`) which then can be injected in a controller and then called for all view models in order to initialize them. You can inject all the dependencies (caching, repositories etc) in this initializer. See the code sample below:

```cs
public class Foo { }

public class Bar { }

public abstract class Layout
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> FooList { get; set; }
}

public class HomeViewModel : Layout
{

}

public interface IFooRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> GetList();
}

public interface IBarRepository
{
    Bar GetSingle();
}

public interface ILayoutInitializer
{
    void Initialize(Layout layout);
}

public class LayoutInitializer : ILayoutInitializer
{
    private readonly IFooRepository _fooRepository;
    private readonly IBarRepository _barRepository;

    public LayoutInitializer(IFooRepository fooRepository, IBarRepository barRepository)
    {
        _fooRepository = fooRepository;
        _barRepository = barRepository;
    }

    public void Initialize(Layout layout)
    {
        if (layout is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(layout));

        layout.FooList = _fooRepository.GetList();
        layout.Bar = _barRepository.GetSingle();
    }
}

public class MainController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILayoutInitializer _layoutInitializer;

    public MainController(ILayoutInitializer layoutInitializer)
    {
        _layoutInitializer = layoutInitializer;
    }

    public IActionResult Home()
    {
        var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();

        _layoutInitializer.Initialize(homeViewModel);

        return View(homeViewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a reasonable solution, however it needs to remember, for each concrete class creation, to call the _layoutInitializer.Initialize() method...

Comment: Well, if this is going to be a common behavior for all your view models you can implement the action filter and override its `OnActionExecuted` to access the model and initialize it (`ILayoutInitializer` can be injected in filter's constructor).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a couple of options here:

1. **Property Injection** - Inject your `IMemoryCache` into the property via DI (most containers support it), i would not recommend this approach.

```
public class Foo {
   [Inject] // or other marker attribute specific to your IoC
   public readonly IMemoryCache;
....
}
```

2. **Service Locator** - Use a thread safe, singleton reference to your container and resolve the dependency. I'd also avoid this option.

```
public Foo(): base()
{
  base.MemoryCache = IoC.Resolve<IMemoryCache>();
}
```

3. **Ctor injection from derived to parent** - Although this might be verbose its actually the right thing to do, as you will be explicit about your contracts and dependencies.

```
public Foo(IMemoryCache cache): base(cache)
```

4. **Pass dependency in the method signature** - Very explicit but honours functional programming principles. Eg: Ask yourself is it the whole class which needs that dependency or just one of its methods?

```
public void Foo(IMemoryCache cache, int bar)
```

5. **Ctor injection but pass the container to parent if you have too many dependencies**

```
public Foo(IBar bar, IBaz baz, IContainer container): base(container)
{
  ...
}
```

I had instances where option 5 worked best during heavy refactorings.

Comment: 2 & 5 are same, both are service loctators :)

Comment: Conceptually yes. There are small technicalities depending on which container you are using, and how it manages `scopes`. Eg autofac: injected `ILifetimeScope` vs hard reference to `IContainer` which got assigned post application startup.

Comment: For method 2, where i get  IoC?

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ In your Startup.cs when you compose your IoC container, you'd assign it to a public static field of a class available to all your class libraries.  Then you reference it. Worth mentioning you cannot mix both as you'll end up with a circular reference (registered class needing the container before its created). This is why 5. is better, as you can Inject the "Container" (in autofac called ILifetimeScope) during component registration.

Comment: Ok, but this would cause problems in testing the class because there is an hidden dependency on static IoC member, right?

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ Yes absolutely this is why people hate ServiceLocator.